# How to find out what my MacBook Air was doing for 3 hours in my backpack (hot and at 8% battery) when I thought it was sleeping?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, logs

I am using macOS Catalina (10.15) and I spent about an hour exporting some photos from Photos to my friend's SD card, which seems to involve a lot of computing (it's not the same as copying files). That's OK.

It was plugged in to power the whole time, so I was at 100% battery. When I finished, I closed all the applications except Chrome browser with a single empty tab and closed the lid. This normally puts my laptop into to sleep mode.

I unplugged it and slid it into the protective case in my backpack as I've been doing every day for several years now.

Three hours later, I pulled it out on the bus to do some work and the fan was running, it was hot, and the battery was at 8%.

I took the screenshot below and then shut the computer down so I could safely put it back in its protector.

**Question:** How can I find out what my MacBook Air was doing for 2 hours in my backpack (hot and at 8% battery) when I thought it was sleeping? Are there log files I can check for a few hour period to see what was using so much power?

There is a *very remote* possibility that I had used `sudo pmset -a disablesleep 1` recently to listen to some music with the lid closed on another bus ride, but I doubt it. Nevertheless I need to rule this out.

Is there a way I can check the status of `disablesleep` during that time period, or find logs of the instances when it changed status?

[image: screenshot showing empty tab and 8% remaining power on MacBook Air]

---

**Update 1:** I'm not seeing any way to get an hourly summary unless it's this stuff from Activity Monitor (below) which goes for only 12 hours in my very old Catalina OS. (I will be updating, as soon as I can convince the App store to recognize my Apple ID, perhaps that will solve several lingering problems).

[image: description]

**Update 2:** In response to the suggested queries in @Ruskes's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/469237/143729) here are the results. Note that I put my laptop in my backpack somewhere around 10:45 to 11:45, and then opened it back up around 14:15, noticed the problem and shut it down. I later plugged it in to charge and restarted around 16:00

The command `log show --style syslog --last 36h | grep "Wake reason"` yielded

```
2024-02-13 06:24:18.304815+0800  localhost powerd[109]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "<private>"  identity: "<private>"
2024-02-13 06:24:39.508966+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: TDM0 XHC1
2024-02-13 06:24:39.508967+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: TDM0 XHC1
2024-02-13 06:46:17.830890+0800  localhost corespeechd[651]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2024-02-13 06:46:17.830895+0800  localhost corespeechd[651]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2024-02-13 06:46:18.991668+0800  localhost powerd[109]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "<private>"  identity: "<private>"
2024-02-13 06:46:20.152147+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 06:47:07.548976+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)
2024-02-13 06:47:07.548979+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)
2024-02-13 06:48:04.648201+0800  localhost corespeechd[651]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2024-02-13 06:48:04.648208+0800  localhost corespeechd[651]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2024-02-13 06:48:04.656591+0800  localhost powerd[109]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "<private>"  identity: "<private>"
2024-02-13 06:48:05.642408+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 06:48:05.718097+0800  localhost powerd[109]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "<private>"  identity: "<private>"
2024-02-13 06:48:05.720483+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 06:49:22.965033+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 10:43:53.090984+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (User)
2024-02-13 10:43:53.091000+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (User)
2024-02-13 14:18:40.937986+0800  localhost corespeechd[389]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2024-02-13 14:18:40.938058+0800  localhost corespeechd[389]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2024-02-13 14:18:53.279118+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 15:59:42.233613+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 16:05:38.933380+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2024-02-13 16:05:38.933382+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2024-02-13 16:15:29.675109+0800  localhost corespeechd[382]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2024-02-13 16:15:29.675120+0800  localhost corespeechd[382]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2024-02-13 16:15:31.685736+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 16:16:19.364015+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2024-02-13 16:16:19.364017+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2024-02-13 16:30:30.669710+0800  localhost corespeechd[382]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
[...]
```

The command `log show --style syslog | fgrep "Wake reason"` yielded

```
[...]
2024-02-13 06:24:18.304815+0800  localhost powerd[109]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "<private>"  identity: "<private>"
2024-02-13 06:24:39.508966+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: TDM0 XHC1
2024-02-13 06:24:39.508967+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: TDM0 XHC1
2024-02-13 06:46:17.830890+0800  localhost corespeechd[651]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2024-02-13 06:46:17.830895+0800  localhost corespeechd[651]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2024-02-13 06:46:18.991668+0800  localhost powerd[109]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "<private>"  identity: "<private>"
2024-02-13 06:46:20.152147+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 06:47:07.548976+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)
2024-02-13 06:47:07.548979+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)
2024-02-13 06:48:04.648201+0800  localhost corespeechd[651]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2024-02-13 06:48:04.648208+0800  localhost corespeechd[651]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2024-02-13 06:48:04.656591+0800  localhost powerd[109]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "<private>"  identity: "<private>"
2024-02-13 06:48:05.642408+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 06:48:05.718097+0800  localhost powerd[109]: [powerd:sleepWake] Wake reason: "<private>"  identity: "<private>"
2024-02-13 06:48:05.720483+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 06:49:22.965033+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 10:43:53.090984+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (User)
2024-02-13 10:43:53.091000+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (User)
2024-02-13 14:18:40.937986+0800  localhost corespeechd[389]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2024-02-13 14:18:40.938058+0800  localhost corespeechd[389]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2024-02-13 14:18:53.279118+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 15:59:42.233613+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 16:05:38.933380+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2024-02-13 16:05:38.933382+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2024-02-13 16:15:29.675109+0800  localhost corespeechd[382]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2024-02-13 16:15:29.675120+0800  localhost corespeechd[382]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2024-02-13 16:15:31.685736+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 16:16:19.364015+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2024-02-13 16:16:19.364017+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2024-02-13 16:30:30.669710+0800  localhost corespeechd[382]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2024-02-13 16:30:30.669719+0800  localhost corespeechd[382]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
2024-02-13 16:30:31.804000+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 16:30:31.859119+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2024-02-13 16:31:20.329319+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
2024-02-13 16:31:20.329321+0800  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.RTC (Alarm)
[...]
```

The command `log show --style syslog | fgrep "DarkWake"` is really long, dense, and verbose, and can be read for the next two weeks here in pastebin

- https://pastebin.com/3sR2JrY7

Comment: Can you check activity monitor? If it’s recent you can see [hourly summary of energy usage](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/421572/5472) for a day in the past…

Comment: @bmike thanks, I'm not seeing any way to get an hourly summary unless it's this https://i.stack.imgur.com/or0qa.png which goes for only 12 hours in my very old Catalina OS. (I will be updating, as soon as I can convince the App store to recognize my Apple ID (long story relating to forgotten password at a time when Apple wasn't resetting passwords because of a security breach), perhaps that will solve several lingering problems)

Comment: That’s what I was hoping - iOS seems to have better look back than macOS in the settings app

Comment: By the way - next time, do it other way around: first unplug and THEN close the lid. This is "known bug" for few years. Your notebook (not just MAC, every notebook on earth work like this  ) is remembering "ok, I am plugged in, I can start later and do xxxyyy".

Comment: @Jan'splite'K. *Thanks!* I'll do that from now on.

Comment: @Jan'splite'K. my msi I just can put in the settings "never wake up for updates/whatever" - just like a desktop. I really wouldn't be happy if the screen of my desktop suddenly started lighting up at 4 am waking me as a person up as well.... There must be a setting in apple to change this, I've notice this problem as well and I'm kind of afraid of getting a desktop with apple software now.

Answer (score 22):

You can try to look in terminal what woke it up and for how long

```
log show --style syslog --last 5h | grep "Wake reason" 
log show --style syslog | fgrep "Wake reason"
log show --style syslog | fgrep "DarkWake"
```

If you need help, you can publish your findings in new post here

Comment: Ah this is interesting! Checking all of the above now...

Comment: @uhoh Once you find out what woke it up, it'd be really cool if you posted a self-answer explaining what it was.

Comment: Sometimes life (temporarily) interferes with Stack Exchange. I'm back up to speed and I've updated my post to include results from all three that bracket the relevant time period. Since the third result is so verbose I can't fit it into SE's 30,000 character limit even with severe editing, so I've moved it to pastebin and included the link. That link will expire in two weeks. If you need more detail let me know. *Thanks!*

Comment: it happened again, dropped from 70% to 50% as soon as I closed the lid and put it in the backpack. https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqLJ7.png I'm running the logs again now...

Comment: @gparyani I've posted the results *back into my question*, but omg I can't read that stuff. As far as I can tell those logs are about decisions related to waking up or not, but don't address the question that I've asked: 'How to find out what my MacBook Air was doing...?"

Comment: This happened to me twice. The second time just happened. I had bookmarked this answer to use these commands. I got no entries for that period. Nothing between 14:41 and 20:05 with my laptop heating up after I closed it at around 18:10. I rebooted and began charging it at 20:05. I wonder what else I can try.